# A simple way to replicate/synchronize a production MySQL with a development MySQL

Tags: database, mariadb, synchronization

I'm actually using some MariaDB and operate from HeidiSQL... could you please advice a simple way to keep production databases and development databases synchronized?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean structure or the records too?

Comment: I would need both, the records are specifically complicating me.

Comment: you should also specify where your db is hosted

Comment: Not to offend anyone, but why does it matter? I have SSH access, I can also allow external 3306 connections, and operate as it would be local... excepting for the delays lol